Why am I getting a http 400 error Flutter?
I'm trying to write a code in Flutter that would pick an image with ImagePicker and store it in Firebase as Uint8List using a http request with firebase auth-rest-api. The problem is that I get a 400 error and I don't know why. Here's my function that sends a request
Future<Uint8List?> getImageData(Image? image) async {
    Uint8List? imageData = await image!.uint8List;
    print(imageData);
    return imageData;
  }

Future<void> postImage(String token) async {
    Uint8List? imageData = await getImageData(image);
    final url = Uri.parse(
        "(firebase link)?auth=$token");
    try {
      if (imageData != null) {
        final response = await http.post(
          url,
          body: json.encode(
            {"title": title.text, "imageData": imageData},
          ),
        );
        print(response.statusCode);
      } else {
        throw const HttpException("Photo not selected");
      }
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

I also have my previous function which I used to test if I can store data as Uint8List in firebase and it works normally. Here it is
Future<Uint8List> getBytesFromPhoto() async {
    return (await rootBundle.load("assets/images/Clublogo.png"))
        .buffer
        .asUint8List();
  }

  Future<void> postDbimage(String title, String token) async {
    final Uint8List imageData = await getBytesFromPhoto();

    var responce = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("(firebase link)?auth=$token"),
      body: json.encode(
        {"title": title, "imageData": imageData},
      ),
    );
    print(responce.statusCode);
  }

Here I took a photo from my assets, converted it to Uint8List and stored it normally. I would be very grateful for your answer.
I also tried to connect Firebase with my app directly, did everything like in tutorials, but for some reason it just didn't work by me. For example my file under android/build.gradle doesn't contain a block "buildscript", if I add it, I get a problem with my Kotlin version, if I update Kotlin version, I get another problem and so on. So I just decided to work with Firebase using http-requests. Thanks for your answer

Also if I delete lines that forbid to send a request without imageData and try to just post a title, it works completely normally
